# Installing extension in php

Tags: linux, shell-script, debian, php, webserver

I have a Debian server using Nginx and PHP 5.5.14. It is working properly but I need to install the mcrypt extension on it. Do I need to compile PHP 5.5.14 again to install the extension ?! I read some things and that's what I understood. That I can not just append the extension in the existing installation I need to do a new install. I am wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you read is right.  To install an extension in PHP you have to compile it. While compiling you can remove or add extension as your requirement

Comment: Please rate if you found this post helpful